# Error when referencing type variable from another file

Tags: coq

I am working upon formalization of groups theory in coq. I have 2 files:

- groups.v - contains definitions and theorems for groups
- groups_Z.v - contains theorems and definitions for Z group.

groups.v:

```
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import PeanoNat.

Class Semigroup G : Type :=
{
    mult : G -> G -> G;
    assoc : forall x y z:G,
        mult x (mult y z) = mult (mult x y) z
}.

Class Monoid G `{Hsemi: Semigroup G} : Type :=
{
  e : G;
  left_id : forall x:G, mult e x = x;
}.

Class Group G `{Hmono: Monoid G} : Type :=
{
    inv : G -> G;
    left_inv : forall x:G, mult (inv x) x = e;
}.

Declare Scope group_scope.
Infix "*" := mult (at level 40, left associativity) : group_scope.
Open Scope group_scope.

Section Group_theorems.

  Parameter G: Type.
  Context `{Hgr: Group G}.
  (* More theorems follow *)
  Fixpoint pow (a: G) (n: nat) {struct n} : G :=
    match n with
    | 0 => e
    | S n' => a * (pow a n')
    end.

  Notation "a ** b" := (pow a b) (at level 35, right associativity).

End Group_theorems.
Close Scope group_scope.
```

groups_Z.v:

```
Add LoadPath ".".
Require Import groups.
Require Import ZArith.

Open Scope group_scope.
Section Z_Groups.
  Parameter G: Type.
  Context `{Hgr: Group G}.

  Definition pow_z (a: groups.G) (z: Z) : G :=
    match z with
    | Z0 => e
    | Zpos x => pow a (Pos.to_nat x)
    | Zneg x => inv (pow a (Pos.to_nat x))
    end.

  Notation "a ** b" := (pow_z a b) (at level 35, right associativity).
End Z_groups.
Close Scope group_scope.
```

The attempt to define `pow_z` fails with message:

> The term "pow a (Pos.to_nat x)" has type "groups.G" while it is
> expected to have type "G".

If we use the different signature: `Definition pow_z (a: G) (z: Z) : G`

instead of `Definition pow_z (a: groups.G) (z: Z) : G`.

then it gives another error:

> The term "a" has type "G" while it is expected to have type
> "groups.G".

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `Parameter G: Type.` to `Variable G: Type` in both files and `pow_z` definition to this:

```
Definition pow_z (a: G) (z: Z) : G :=
    match z with
    | Z0 => e
    | Zpos x => pow G a (Pos.to_nat x)
    | Zneg x => inv (pow G a (Pos.to_nat x))
    end.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Coq, the command `Parameter G : Type` declares a global constant, which is akin to axiomatizing the existence of an abstract Type  `G : Type`. From a theoretical point of view, this should be ok as this axiom is trivially realizable, but I think you meant `Variable G : Type` to denote a local variable instead.

The errors messages of Coq follow from there because you declare two global constants named `G`, one in each module. As soon as the second one is declared, the first one is designated by `groups.G` by Coq (it's the shortest name that disambiguates this constant from others). Now `pow` operates on and returns a `groups.G`, while you require `pow_z` returns a `G` (which in file `groups_Z.v` at this location means `groups_Z.G`, and is different from `groups.G`).

NB: Group theory has been developed several times in Coq, and if you want to do anything else than experimenting with the system, I would advise you work on top of existing libraries. For example the mathematical components library has a [finite group library](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/fb9fb240fe7f6a99035a4db23942cb774458d7a3/mathcomp/fingroup).